# Setting up personal branch permissions using gitolite

Tags: git, permissions, branch, gitolite

I'm having some issues getting personal branch permissions set up using gitolite.

gitolite.conf:

```
repo    ulul
RW+     =   @admins
RW+ personal/USER/      =   @devs
R       =   @devs
- = @devs
```

Error message (when pushing):
    W refs/heads/jesse jesse DENIED by refs/.*

Relevant piece from the compiled gitolite file:
   `'jesse' => [

      [

        8,

        'refs/.*',

        'R'

      ],

      [

        16,

        "refs/heads/personal/$gl_user/",

        'RW+'

      ],

      [

        24,

        'refs/.*',

        '-'

      ]

    ],`

Comment: Someone got terribly confused by your answer and decided he needed to use $gl_user in the gitolite.conf file. Please do not supply answers that expose internals. I don't mean it in any "this is a secret" manner, but only in a "please don't confuse noobs" manner :-) (In other words, if someone wants to hack at gitolite that's a valid detail to discuss but not when someone wants to just *use* it). Thanks Sitaram

Comment: @Sitaram gitolite is a very good software. I never expected to see its developer leaving such a pedant comment. *disappointment*

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Turns out the personal/USER/ is just the namespace; so creating branches like personal/jesse/main works fine.  Hope this helps future gitolite users.

Answer (score 1):

To detail your own answer, the important part is:

```
"refs/heads/personal/$gl_user/"
```

`$gl_user` is the variable set after the name passed in parameter of the scripts called ssh in its [forced command mechanism](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858).
That name is the one of the public key registered through gitolite.